# How get started with drupal10 on localhost?

Tags: installation, drupal

I'm trying to prototype a drupal10 site on a macOS localhost, where I already have apache and mysql installed and running. I already used:

```
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project ~/Sites/mysite
```

To /etc/hosts, I added:

```
127.0.0.1   mysite.local
```

I'll add modules and a theme later.

But what, exactly do I do next to access and begin adding content to the drupal10 site?

The many and varied sources of documentation, including the INSTALL.txt file, are quite confusing and even seemingly contradictory as to what else needs to be done.

What, exactly do I do next to access and begin adding content to the drupal10 site?

Docs say that the drupal installer creates the mysql database, but exactly what exactly do I need to do further to "install" the site and thereby to have the database created.

And what url do I use? I tried mysite.local, but apache does not find such a site.

Please be explicit (and gentle!).

Comment: Sounds like you need to tell apache that your url points to your sites directory via a [virtualhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) though it has been a long time since I did it that way. Many drupal devs tend to spin up local docker containers via [Lando](https://lando.dev/) these days.

Comment: @2pha: That was the problem. I now added the vhost and was able to access and work through the drupal configuration through the browser. Thanks.

Comment: But after login as admin, changing a color and the page header, after I logged out, I navigated to the front page and attempted to log in. But I got a Page not found error. How to fix this?

Comment: I have added an answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75966572/drupal-10-localhost-site-how-access-login-page-after-installation-and-logging-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions:

**What, exactly do I do next to access and begin adding content to the drupal10 site?**
If your installation log (that long text on yout terminal, after you type the composer command) don't show any errors you need to create a database to your Drupal website:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal/step-3-create-a-database

After the creation of the database, you need to configure your installation and after that you can run the installer. On your browser access: `/core/install.php`

**And what url do I use?**
Have you tryed access **http://mysite.local**?

You see, as you said that's the URL you have point your enviroment, "telling" to apache point your localhost to this URL.

This is the official Drupal guide:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/installing-drupal

But if you prefer, I have a suggestion that will make your life a lot easier. Use **Lando**:

https://docs.lando.dev/drupal/getting-started.html

It will create a virtual machine, much easier to configure and use.

Comment: I configured a virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf that includes the setting "Allow Override All". This allowed me to navigate to the usual drupal configuration page, connect to the mysql database, etc. But after login as admin, changing a color and the page header, after I logged out, I navigated to the front page and attempted to log in. But I got a Page not found error. How to fix this?

Comment: When you trying to login again… what is the path of the login page that you are trying to access and returning this error?