# drupal 10 localhost site: How access login page after installation and logging out

Tags: drupal

​
With a (MacPorts) AMP stack, I used composer to set up a locahost drupal 10 site and created the mysql database. To `httpd-vhosts.conf`, I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myname@emailprovider.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/mysite/web"
    ServerName mysite.local
    ServerAlias www.mysite.local
    ErrorLog  "var/log/apache2/drupal-error_log"
    CustomLog "var/log/apache2/drupal-access_log" common
    <Directory /Users/me/Sites/mysite/web>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then by browsing to `mysite.local`, I got the drupal configuration page and went through everything, choosing the Standard configuration, setting up the admin account, connecting to the database, etc., without error. Then I logged out there.

I can still access the front page. But when I click the Log in link from the menu on the front page, the URL shown in the browser is http://mysite.local/web/user/login, but I get a Page not found error.

What is the remedy?

​

Answer (score 1):

Your installation seems to be adding the "web" folder to the base path so the  links on the page include this extra folder.
I would have to assume that navigating to the correct url http://mysite.local/user/login works

You can try to uncomment the [RewriteBase in the .htaccess file](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.0.7/.htaccess#L114) and hopefully that will fix your problem.

Comment: No, using `http://mysite.local/user/login` after I've logged out gives me the same Page no found error. Also, the `.htaccess` file in `~/Sites/mysite/web` has no `RewriteBase` in it; nor doe the `.htaccess` file in `~/Sites/mysite/web/sites/default/files`.

Comment: go through the steps on [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/228462)

Comment: After browsing directly to http://mysite.local/web/user/login and again getting a Page not found error message, the next time I browed to http://mysite.local and clicked the Log in button, I *was* able to complete a login.

I have no idea why that fixed the problem, but it worked!